# Facitiy to select username after facebook connect on django application

Tags: facebook, django-forms, django-urls

I am working on integration of django application with facebook and i did almost but I want to give an facility to the user to select his/her username after he/she successfully logged in facebook on my django site here is the code :

form for usename :

class RegisterUsernameForm(forms.Form):

```
username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',
                            max_length=30,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                            label=_(u'username'))

def clean_username(self):
    """
    Validate that the username is alphanumeric and is not already
    in use.

    """
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return self.cleaned_data['username']
    raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'This username is already taken. Please choose another.'))
```

made an template against it as well

here is the view which i used to use the from

def register_username(request, form_class=RegisterUsernameForm,
             template_name='registration/register_username_form.html',
             extra_context=None):

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form['username'].data
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('facebook_settings'))
    else:
        form = form_class()

    if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value
    return render_to_response(template_name,
                          { 'form': form },
                          context_instance=context)
```

in which i am just getting the username from the from...

I have one fb_authenticate on my django application in which i am check whether user exist in my db or not if not then create new one at that point of time i need to redirect that form "username" which i have above mention . so user can select it and then will register him in dgango app

class FbBackend:

```
def fb_authenticate(self, request, facebook_id=None):
    if not facebook_id: return None
    try:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(facebook_id=facebook_id)

        #To Check whether the same user is loggin in to facebook if not then logout the perivous one and login new one.
        if request.user != profile.user :
           from django.contrib.auth import logout
           logout(request)
           request.user=profile.user

        UpdateFbUserDetails(request, profile.user, facebook_id)
        return profile.user
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        # No user. Create one.
        pass

    #Get user facebook account details like first name, last name and email address. 
    username = request.facebook.users.getInfo([request.facebook.uid], ['name'])[0]['name']
    firstname = request.facebook.users.getInfo([request.facebook.uid], ['first_name'])[0]['first_name']
    lastname = request.facebook.users.getInfo([request.facebook.uid], ['last_name'])[0]['last_name']
    emailaddress = request.facebook.users.getInfo([request.facebook.uid], ['email'])[0]['email']

    # Create the username for facebook logged in user 
    fbusername = (emailaddress.rsplit ('@')[0]).replace ('.','') + "_"+((emailaddress.rsplit ('@')[1])[0]).capitalize()


    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=emailaddress)
        # This shouldn't really happen. Log an error.
        # logging.error('Strange: user %s already exists.' % username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create_user(fbusername,emailaddress,'xxxx')#('fb_%s' % facebook_id, '')
        user.first_name = firstname 
        user.last_name = lastname

    if not UpdateFbUserDetails(request, user, facebook_id):
        return None
    user.save()
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    profile.facebook_id = facebook_id
    new_basics_info = UserBasicInfo()
    new_basics_info.full_name = username
    new_basics_info.save()
    profile.basics_info = new_basics_info
    new_personal_info = UserPersonalInfo()
    new_personal_info.save()
    profile.personal_info = new_personal_info
    profile.save()
    return user
```

Please help me how i can achieve it......

Thanks

Ansh J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it ....

I just put all the saving code in view file after :

if form.is_valid():
 and the when user is logged in I navigate him to that page and when he select join then will get registered in my django application .